# How can I do string manipulation in fish shell

Tags: fish, string-manipulation

How can I do bash style string manipulations in Fish shell?

Specifically, in bash

```
read branch < ".git/HEAD"
branch=${branch#ref: refs/heads/}
```

will put the branch name in `$branch` variable.

How can I do the same in fish shell?

I glanced over documentation of fish but didn't find anything.

Comment: I already got this working with `sed`. I was wondering if fish has something builtin.

Answer (score 6):

The fish shell now has a `string` builtin command.

To use `string` instead of `sed` in your case:

```
set branch (string replace 'ref: refs/heads/' '' <.git/HEAD)
```

It can operate on given arguments, or on standard input.

There's lots more that `string` can do. From the [string command documentation](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/commands.html#string):

```
Synopsis

string length [(-q | --quiet)] [STRING...]
string sub [(-s | --start) START] [(-l | --length) LENGTH] [(-q | --quiet)]
           [STRING...]
string split [(-m | --max) MAX] [(-r | --right)] [(-q | --quiet)] SEP
             [STRING...]
string join [(-q | --quiet)] SEP [STRING...]
string trim [(-l | --left)] [(-r | --right)] [(-c | --chars CHARS)]
            [(-q | --quiet)] [STRING...]
string escape [(-n | --no-quoted)] [STRING...]
string match [(-a | --all)] [(-i | --ignore-case)] [(-r | --regex)]
             [(-n | --index)] [(-q | --quiet)] [(-v | --invert)] PATTERN [STRING...]
string replace [(-a | --all)] [(-i | --ignore-case)] [(-r | --regex)]
               [(-q | --quiet)] PATTERN REPLACEMENT [STRING...]
```

Answer (score 3):

fish is all about minimalism: if there's a common utility that does the job easily, it's not in fish. So, as you say, with sed:

```
set branch (sed 's#^ref: refs/heads/##' .git/HEAD)
```